# Shared Google Sheet (Editor Access for Collaborator), with Custom UI TemplateHtml, serves html, but does not append row. Works for Sheet Owner

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, authorization, collaboration

I have a working (working for me, the owner of the sheet/ app script) apps script that allows a user to enter any customer interaction. The user is a collaborator on the Sheet, with Editor access.

When the collaborator runs the custom menu item, a html is served (Template), but when the collaborator hits Submit, the data does not get appended to the specified tab on the spreadsheet. This works fine if I run it, though.

Reading a bit of the documentation seems to suggest an Authmode issue? Any pointers gratefully appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my CODE.GS

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Customer Engagement')
      .addItem('Record Interaction', 'showDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('RecordInteraction.html');
  html.data = readData();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate().setWidth(400).setHeight(600), 'Please Enter Details');
}

function readData() {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Ms0Cny3f-XaXS26s5AnrDT4H9c8p8OKRfwxPIQ9_CU/edit#gid=16760772"; 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Pipeline");
  var rng = ws.getRange('D2:D')
  var rangeArray = rng.getValues();
  var filArray = rangeArray.filter(function (el) {return el[0] != ""}).flat();  // Modified
  console.info("hello read the data")
  return filArray;
}

function activateSheetById(sheetId) {
 
  //Access all the sheets in the Google Sheets spreadsheet
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();

  //Filter out sheets whose Ids do not match
  var sheetsForId = sheets.filter(function(sheet) {
    return sheet.getSheetId() === sheetId;
  });

  //If a sheet with the Id was found, activate it
  if(sheetsForId.length > 0)
    sheetsForId[0].activate();
}

function appendRowFromFormSubmit(form) {
  var row = [form.name, form.doi, form.mode, form.feedback, form.temperature];
  console.info("Appending Row");
  activateSheetById(2059810756);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow(row);
}

function RemoveMenu() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     ss.removeMenu('Customer Contact');
}
```

Here is my HTML+JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
     label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    }   
    </style>
    
  <base target="_top">
  <script>
    function submitForm() {
      google.script.run.appendRowFromFormSubmit(document.getElementById("feedbackForm"));
      document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("thanks").style.display = "block";
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <datalist id="datalist">
    <? 
    data.forEach(e => { 
    ?>
    <option value="<?= e ?>">
    <? }); ?>
  </datalist>
  <div>
  <div id="form">
  <h1>Record Interaction</h1>
  <form id="feedbackForm">
    <label for="name">Parent Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" list="datalist"><br><br>

    <label for="doi">Date of Interaction</label>
    <input id="today" type="date" name="doi"><br><br>

    <label for="mode">Mode of Interaction (WA/Call/Email/Other)</label>
    <input type="text" id="mode" name="mode"><br><br>

    <label for="feedback">Interaction Summary</label>
    <textarea rows=4 cols=35 id="feedback" name="feedback">Enter Interaction Summary Here...
         </textarea><br><br>

    <div>
      <label for="temperature">Likely Candidate?</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="Hot" name="temperature" value="Hot">
      <label for="yes">Hot</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="Warm" name="temperature" value="Warm">
      <label for="yes">Warm</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="Tepid" name="temperature" value="Tepid">
      <label for="yes">Tepid</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="Cold" name="temperature" value="Cold">
      <label for="no">Cold</label><br><br>

      <input type="button" value="Submit Interaction" onclick="submitForm();">
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="thanks" style="display: none;">
    <p>Thank you for speaking to our customers!</p>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: does the sheet have any "Protected Ranges"?

Comment: no protected ranges on the sheet, I am afraid. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved!!! It was a matter of being logged into Google on 2 different accounts. Use a private browsing window, and there's no problem!